# how do i update the video source to play a new video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, html5-video, src

I'm trying to update the `src` source property of a html5 video in order to play a new video selected from a list by the user. The selected video file is stored inside the `fileSelected` variable. The `src` is changing each time a new video is selected, but the html5 video player itself continues to play the old video. Anyone know where im going wrong? Here is the relevant code:

```
function Videos({files,fileSelected}){
    var page =null
    console.log(fileSelected)

    if(!fileSelected && files){
        fileSelected= files[0][0]
        page = <SecondPage files = {files} fileSelected={fileSelected}/> 
    }
    else if(files && fileSelected){
        page = <SecondPage files = {files} fileSelected={fileSelected}/> 
    }else if(!files){
        page = <FirstPage files = {files} fileSelected={fileSelected}/>

    }
    return(page)
}

export default Videos






function FirstPage({files,fileSelected}){
    return(<div> <h2> No Video Uploaded </h2></div>)
}



class SecondPage extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    render(){
        const {files, fileSelected}=this.props;
        var src

        return(

                <div>
                    { src = (fileSelected) ? URL.createObjectURL(fileSelected): URL.createObjectURL(files[0][0])}

                    <div className="ui one column centered grid">
                        <div className="one wide column"> {/*needs to be one wide here not just column for center to work*/}
                            <h3>Videos</h3>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div className="ui grid">
                        <div className="ten wide column">
                            <video controls width="566" height="320">
                                    <source src={src} id='video' type="video/mp4" />
                                    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                            </video>
                        </div>

                        <div className="six wide column">
                            {files[1]}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            )

    }
}
```

Note that the `files` variable contains all the videos the user can choose from.

Comment: are you using `PureComponent` on this?

Comment: @Semi-Friends no im not using that

Answer (score 0):

When you change the source of a HTML5 video element you also need to tell the element to load to make it actually load the new source.

The example below, which is function rather than class based and uses hooks, works well. It essentially watches the source property (using useEffect) and then reloads the video when the source changes.

```js
const MyVideo = forwardRef( (props, ref) => {
  // This component represents a single video element.
  // It includes a forward ref which means it passes it ref back to its parent
  // so it's partent can use the ref too

  const reloadSource = (newSource) => {
    //Function to reload the video element with a new source
    let vidElement = ref.current;
    if (vidElement) {
      vidElement.load();
    }
  };

  useEffect (reloadSource, [props.source]);

  return(
    <div className="video-wrapper">
        <video className="video-area" controls ref={ref}>
          <source src={props.source} type="video/mp4"/>
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
  )
});
```