# different video src on mobile and device don't work

Tags: reactjs, video, next.js

I am looking for a solution where I can play two different video files per device (desktop/mobile). Using a react hook I have written a function that returns whether the viewport is desktop or mobile. In the video component I have the following code.

```
 {isMobile && block.imagePortrait?.url ? (
     <video autoPlay muted loop className={'no'}>
     <source src={block.imagePortrait.url + '?c=' + cacheBuster} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
 ) : (
      <video autoPlay muted loop className={'xy'}>
      <source src={block.imageLandscape.url + '?c=' + cacheBuster} type="video/mp4" />
     </video>
)}
```

In the console, the SRC code of the film changes fine, but in the browser (Firefox/Chrome and Safari) itself, the desktop version is always displayed.

I installed the "cacheBuster" as a first potential solution so that the browser reloads the file. But it did not help. Thanks for your tips

Comment: Provide full code how you are defining/importing (isMobile && block.imagePortrait?.url)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a common problem as its not that intuitive always but when you change the source of a HTML5 video element you also need to tell the element to load to make it actually load the new source.

You can see a react example here that I've used and that works as expected: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75225060/334402