# Changing video source for media queries

Tags: reactjs, next.js, html5-video

React/Next.js with tax Setup. I'm need a solution to update video source by media query. Based on [how do i update the video source to play a new video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58024880/how-do-i-update-the-video-source-to-play-a-new-video/75225060#75225060) I build the following solution. It works nicely on dev mod:

My Code:

````
  const [isMobile, cacheBuster] = useIsMobile()

  const MyVideo = forwardRef((props, ref: React.Ref<HTMLVideoElement | null>) => {
    const reloadSource = (newSource: string) => {
      let vidElement = ref.current
      if (vidElement) {
        vidElement.load()
      }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      reloadSource(props.source)
    }, [props.source])

    MyVideo.displayName = 'MyVideo'

    return (
      <>
       
        Video-Test
        {isMobile ? (
          <div>
            <video autoPlay muted loop playsInline className={'no'} ref={ref}>
              <source
                src="https://xxx/coming_soon_9x16_low.mp4?c=2"
                type="video/mp4"
              />
            </video>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <video autoPlay muted loop playsInline className={'xy'} ref={ref}>
              <source
                src="https://xxx/coming_soon_16x9.mp4?c=1"
                type="video/mp4"
              />
            </video>
          </div>
        )}
      </>
    )
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <MyVideo ref={useRef(null)} />
    </div>
  )
} ```

But if I try to build I'm getting the following error: 
"Type error: 'ref' is possibly 'null'."

thanks for help and showing me what's wrong..
````